# Get public key from certificate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl

I need to get a server's public key from its SSL cert. I'm getting the cert as follows:

```
https.request(options, res => {
  const cert = res.connection.getPeerCertificate();
  const publicKey = cert.????()
}
```

I can't find a way to get the public key from the certificate though. Are there any libraries that can do this?

I'm looking to use the public key to encrypt some data:

```
const encryptedBuffer =  crypto.publicEncrypt({
  key: publicKey,
  padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
}, utf8Payload)
```

I see that the certificate has a "raw" buffer, but using that as the publicKey fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see that the certificate has a "raw" buffer, but using that as the
>   publicKey fails.

Note that the raw buffer is DER encoded, and from [crypto.publicEncrypt](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer) needs a PEM encoded key. So, you just need to do the conversion. I've used [node-openssl-wrapper](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-openssl-wrapper) in the example below, but there are other libraries that also convert DER to PEM,

```
const ossl = require('openssl-wrapper')
const https = require("https");

https.request(options, res => {
    const certificate = res.connection.getPeerCertificate();
    const rawDer = certificate.raw;

    ossl.exec('x509', rawDer, { inform: 'der', outform: 'pem' }, (err, buffer) => {
        const publicKey = buffer.toString('utf8'); // PEM encoded public key safe to use now
        // crypto.publicEncrypt({ key: publicKey, ...
    })
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID3DCCAsSgAwIBAgIUOaZ5jqRgBz4HjwilIbDz5+Polh0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwXjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ04xEzARBgNVBAoTClRlbnBheS5jb20xHTAbBgNVBAsT
.....
C1c3RqArBaz/c4SqHhyKaHRFinDs5kjnAz+H4+QvQAH0UXgHG050YEZjeZPXMRJB
4I0fzGC++82WXhcwSPaX+BJZuv2bEIfxbyxdVanGmIJdYsGFwSc9sIf2j1cK22A5
vdboEXXkQnqF552iNy9HGRubNQ1VkqITELToRcqcvAo=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If the format of the certificate is as above, it can be done with `crypto` module. No dependency on other packages.

```js
crypto.createPublicKey(cert).export({type:'spki', format:'pem'})

output format:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
..........................
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

or

```js
crypto.createPublicKey(cert).export({type:'pkcs1', format:'pem'})

output format:
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
..............................
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

[see more on the document](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key)

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one (likely because of modern Node.JS support for this, and not a flaw in the original accepted).

Comment: Upvote because this answer is better than accepted ans