# Why I am facing error in verifying a JWT token using `jsonwebtoken` module?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, public-key

I am working on a Next.js app using Firebase authentication. I have managed to implement an authentication system that also generates a session-cookie (in simple words a token we get after successful authentication using `getIdToken()`). I need to verify it in my app for some reasons. As per the official documentation of Firebase:

> Finally, ensure that the ID token was signed by the private key
> corresponding to the token's kid claim. Grab the public key from
> https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
> and use a JWT library to verify the signature. Use the value of
> max-age in the Cache-Control header of the response from that endpoint
> to know when to refresh the public keys.

I don't understand how can I verify the token using the same. I have simply copy-pasted key from the URL provided above and replaced all `\n` with new line. Here is what I have tried:

```
const publicKey = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCsz8sS5pS6KBoX1ph7IXEdfUhv
  PA7S5Eg5B9sPSLrEVtowMGXxpVSJXoJdN8aPP8NrZq0MhW1dHL//Uqg0TTtBv+8F
  IV9SgXrrbHv7jFtwWWqSALwy6XFs+hPi2ES7OOIPxKtkm1n8tMF0dTjrxPR56xCz
  qwuewD5JGJhPWdgJbQIDAQAB
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----`

  jwt.verify(
    cookieValue,
    publicKey,
    { algorithms: ["RS256"] },
    (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Token verification failed:", err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Token verified successfully:", decoded);
      }
    }
  );
```

But I am getting error: `Token verification failed: secretOrPublicKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256` each time. I have tried to put the key in different string formats but still.

Comment: I think it might be something with how you format the public key string. Maybe try to put it in a file, and make sure you don't add any extra spaces or characters, then use node's `fileReadSync` to read the content and pass it to `jwt.verify`.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I have tried that also, I have removed extra spaces, replaced each '\n' with new line and pasted it into a separate file with .pem type. But then error changed to something else (maybe the file is not a key)

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski, I am confused whether I have to simply copy-paste the key from the above mentioned URL or we need to convert it into something else. It is starting and ending with '----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----', however, if it was a key it should have started with 'BEGIN PUBLIC KEY'

Comment: Ah, that might be the problem. That it's a cert, not a key. Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48872869/get-public-key-from-certificate-in-nodejs